# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta mi función más de una vez cuando hago click en mi botón?

Tags: javascript, dom

No sé donde está el error...

Me pasa q al clickear en "CLICK PARA CAMBIAR" me ejecuta  la función solo una vez. Si quiero volver a cambiar el texto no me deja, simplemente no pasa nada al clickear en "CLICK PARA CAMBIAR". Es decir, me permite hacer el cambio de texto solo una vez.

Dejo código:

```js
function barraEditAcerdeMi() {
 // Cada vez q aprieto este botón (el cual tiene su función en "onclick" q es la q estoy definiendo acá) aparecen estos dos elementos, el 1ro es el input donde escribiré el nuevo texto, y el otro elemento es el botón q al presionar hará los cambios. Acá simplemente los hago visibles. 
  document.getElementById("tituloNuevo").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("botonCambiarTexto").style.display = "block";
}
    
function editarAcercaDeMi() {
  // Esta funcion es la q se ejecutará al apretar el botón mencionado, es decir, se reemplazará el texto existente por el texto nuevo (el q escriba en el input)
  document.getElementById("pAcercaDeMi").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tituloNuevo").value;
}
```

```html
<body>
     <div class="parrafo">
        <p id="pAcercaDeMi"><button type="button" id="botonCambiarTexto" onclick="editarAcercaDeMi()"; display:none">CAMBIAR TEXTO</button><input style="display: none;" type="text" id="tituloNuevo"> Este texto se reemplazará por otro al clickear el botón</p>
     </div>
     <div type="button" onclick="barraEditAcerdeMi()">CLICK PARA CAMBIAR<i class="fas fa-pen-square" id="editAdeMi" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 5px;"></i>
     </div>
         
    </body>
```

El error q me aparece en consola al querer ejecutar la función por 2da vez es: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes realizar las siguiente correcciones:

1. Error tipográfico aqui:

```
onclick="editarAcercaDeMi()"; display:none"
```

debes dejarlo así:

```
onclick="editarAcercaDeMi()" style="display:none"
```

2. Error de posición y concepto aquí:

```
Este texto se reemplazará por otro al clickear el botón</p>
```

que debes cambiarlo, por ejemplo, por esto:

```
</p>
<div id="textoACambiar">
    Este texto se reemplazará por otro al clickear el botón
</div>
```

porque así lo quitas del elemento `<p id="pAcercaDeMi">`, que luego equivocadamente sobreescribes completamente en tu función `editarAcercaDeMi()`, y por eso luego no te permite volver a cambiarlo, porque ya no existe.

Al ponerlo en un elemento distinto, en este caso un `<div>` con un id distinto (`textoACambiar`), podrás sobreescribirlo de forma individual, y no todo el párrafo como hasta ahora.

3. Modifica esto en la función `editarAcercaDeMi()`:

```
document.getElementById("pAcercaDeMi").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tituloNuevo").value;
```

por esto otro:

```
document.getElementById("textoACambiar").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tituloNuevo").value;
```

para que, efectivamente, el cambio se realice en el nuevo `<div>` que contiene el texto a modificar.

Ya nos dirás si te así te funciona como pretendes.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! ahí me funcionó! Estoy aprendiendo je, perdón por lo novata. Muy clara tu respuesta...También soy nueva en este sitio, así q estoy aprendiendo a utilizarlo, creo q no me deja darte puntos x ser nueva XD. Si hay otra forma de "valorar" tu respuesta, decime. Gracias!!

Comment: jeje, no pasa nada, ya has hecho lo correcto, que era aceptar la respuesta, asi la comunidad lo verá y tambien podran aprender de ella, y la pregunta no quedará pendiente de respuesta eternamente. Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento del sitio!  Si te lees [ask]  y realizas el [tour] aprenderás lo básico del sitio y además ganarás tu primera medalla! Saludos!